# postincrement operator interesting behaviour in Math.min()

Tags: java, post-increment

I have a question,
  In `Java`, does `Math.min` bind tighter than `++`?
  Let me illustrate with an example and maybe someone can explain to me why I get the results I get.

Here's a method I run:

```
private static void testIncrement() {
    int x=10;
    System.out.println(x++);
    System.out.println(x);

    x=10;
    System.out.println("-----------");
    System.out.println(++x);
    System.out.println(x);

    x=10;
    System.out.println("-----------\n"+x); //10
    x=Math.min(255, x++); 
    System.out.println(x); **//x=10 WHY NOT x=11?**

    x=10;
    System.out.println("-----------\n"+x);
    x=Math.min(255, ++x);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

The results are:

```
10
11
-----------
11
11
-----------
10
10
-----------
10
11
```

On the line where I put `//x=10 WHY NOT x=11?`
I wonder why `x` is 10 and not 11. Maybe someone can explain this to me.

It looks as if `Math.min` create a copy of `x` (which is 10 at this time) which it uses to do `Math.min`. Then the original `x` is incremented from 10 to 11, but the copy which is still 10 comes out of `Math.min` and overwrites the incremented one.

Does this make sense?
Does anyone have an explanation for why x is 10 and not 11 in this case?

Thanks

PS - I totally understand [How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/explain-working-of-post-and-pre-increment-operator-in-java)

Comment: Because the x is incremented after the value 10 is passed to the Math.min method. But before the assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's deconstruct this line:

```
x = Math.min(255, x++);
```

The `x++` means "remember the original value of `x`; then increment `x`; then the value of the expression is the original value". All of this happens *before* the assignment. So it's equivalent to:

```
int tmp = x;               // x = 10, tmp = 10
x = x + 1;                 // x = 11, tmp = 10
x = Math.min(255, tmp);    // x = 10
```

Hopefully that should make it clear. In particular, this has nothing to do with `Math.min` itself - it's just behaving as a normal method invocation. See [section 15.14.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) for more details.

Comment: I agree, but then why is my program outputting 10 both times, instead of 11. After all, it is doing a post increment. Any idea?

Comment: @Adrian: The increment is after the evaluation of the expression, but *before* the assignment of the value returned from the method call... so the value of `x` ends up as 10 (which is what `Math.min` returns). Read the "expansion" - I'll add some comments.

Comment: oh I see it, I missed the temp in x = Math.min(255, tmp). Thanks! :)