# Behavior of Java Postincrementor

Tags: java, post-increment

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = a++;

    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Why does the code above print 1? I was told that a++ means you would get the value of a. then increment it. But the code above never incremented a and just printed 1. Could someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: `a` does get incremented. You are printing `b`.

Comment: http://www.dailyfreecode.com/Code/increment-decrement-operators-1375.aspx

Comment: you are assigning the value of a to b .and incrementing a

Comment: Yes but b is assigned a++, wouldn't that increment a and give that value to b?

Comment: No, it gives the value of a to b and then increments a.

Comment: Have a look at this to get better undersatnding --- > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/explain-working-of-post-and-pre-increment-operator-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works as expected; Here is the code explained:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // a is assigned the value 1
    int a = 1;
    // b is assigned the value of a (1) and THEN a is incremented.
    // b is now 1 and a is 2.
    int b = a++;

    System.out.println(b);
    // if you had printed a here it would have been 2
}
```

This is the same code but with pre-increment of a:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // a is assigned the value 1
    int a = 1;
    // a is incremented (now 2) and THEN b is assigned the value of a (2) 
    // b is now 2 and so is a.
    int b = ++a;

    System.out.println(b);
    // if you had printed a here it would have been 2 so is b.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving an example of pre increment as well!

Answer (score 0):

`int b = a++` is equivalent to `int b = a; a += 1`.  When you print `b`, `a==2 && b==1`

Answer (score 0):

`a++`  is like saying `a`-then increment `a` by 1. So after you say `b = a++`, `b = 1` and `a = 2`.

If you were to preincrement `b = ++a`, you would get `b = 2` Preincrement increases before it assigns value.

Conclustion

> a++ assign value before incrementing 
>   ++a increments, then assigns value.

Answer (score 0):

```
The reason is is as follow.

If it is i++, then equalent code is like this.

result = i;
i = i+1;
return result


If it is ++i. then the equlent code is like this.
i=i+1;
result =i;
return i

So considering your case, even though the value of i is incremented, the returned value is old value. (Post increment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Post Increment Meaning = First complete assignment then Increment.
Pre Increment Meaning = First Increment then assign .

ex:

```
int a=0,b;
b=a++; // ie. Step1(First complete assignment): b=0, then a++ ie a=a+1; so a=1 now.
System.out.println(b); // prints 0
System.out.println(a); // prints 1
```

if

```
int a=0,b;
b=++a; // ie. Step1(First Increment ): a++ ie a=a+1; so a=1 now, b=a , ie b=1.
System.out.println(b); // prints 1
System.out.println(a); // prints 1
```