# Why if (date++ >= 25) is false when date = 24?

Tags: java

It should print the if statement, but instead prints the else... I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
boolean age = true;
int date = 24;

if ( age == true && date++ >= 25 )
     System.out.println( "Exto Libra" );
else
     System.out.println( "No go, sorry" );
```

Comment: Use `++date` and look into the differences between post- and pre-increment.

Comment: you should use ++date.See this live example http://ideone.com/SeKjCw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/explain-working-of-post-and-pre-increment-operator-in-java

Comment: I guess this is some kind of Java puzzle you stumbled over. Don't use increment operators like this, as they can be confusing - obviously.
So, don't even use a pre-increment operator; increment your date BEFORE your if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because `date++` is a post increment expression which means the statement is executed first and then the value of the variable is changed. below is the difference between post and pre operators according to [this source](http://javaques.com/difference-between-post-increment-n-and-pre-incrementn/)

> Post Increment(n++) : First execute the statement then increase the value by one.
>
> Pre Increment (++n) : First increase the value by one then execute the statement.

There is also very nice explanation and java tutorials on java documents site [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

And in your case you are doing this,

```
//This is post increment so else block will be executed
if ( age == true && date++ >= 25 ) //on the execution of this statement the value of date is still 24
   System.out.println( "Exto Libra" );
else
   System.out.println( "No go, sorry" );
```

instead of this,

```
//But if you use ++date as below then if condition will execute
if ( age == true && ++date >= 25 ) //on the execution of this statement the value of date is 25
   System.out.println( "Exto Libra" );
else
   System.out.println( "No go, sorry" );
```

Answer (score 3):

You should change `date++` to `++date`

when you write `date++`, it first take the value of `date` and only after adds it 1.

when you write `++date`, it first adds 1 and then takes the value. so in your case, when it makes the comparison `date++ >= 25` , the value of `date` is still 24

example:

```
int i = 7;
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(i++);
System.out.println(i);
```

output:

```
7
7
8
```

and

```
int i = 7;
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(++i);
System.out.println(i);
```

output:

```
7
8
8
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prepend ++ into the date so it is executed first than the logical operation.

also you can use if(age) instead of if(age==true).

Comment: How will this help with the `if`?

Comment: Dont be so upset Joao, your answer is not clear. You write code to make him understand that `if (age)` is the same as `if (age == true)`  which as nothing to do with the question even if it's totally true. But you don't write code for your solution to the `date++` problem. And again, you don't explain why `date++ >= 25` is not working IN the if :)

Comment: ok, i'll give you that maybe my answer doesn't highlight what it should highlight. edited it

Answer (score 0):

this is going in else because post decrement operator ("date++" in this case) , first uses the variable and checks the condition **date++ >= 25**, and then increments and makes it 25.