# I have some questions regarding this tracing

Tags: java, trace

```
public class Task {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x = 0, p = 0, sum = 0;

    p = 1;
    x = 2;
    double q;
    sum = 0;
    while (p < 12) {
      q = x + p - (sum + 5 / 3) / 3.0 % 2;
      sum = sum + (x++) + (int) q;
      System.out.println(sum);
      if (x > 5)
        p += 4 / 2;
      else
        p += 3 % 1;
    }
    sum = sum + p;
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

While proceeding to line 12 (`sum = sum + (x++) + (int)q;`) i thought sum should be 5 but actually the output is 4. I tried line 12 in the interactions pane and indeed saw that `sum=4`. I don't get it. Shouldn't `x++` yield 3 (x=2) and if this gets added to (int) q ( double q gave me sth like 2.666666), i should be getting 5. Can someone explain to me what happened?

Additionally,after getting my first output, how should I proceed?
The next condition is:

```
if (x > 5)
  p += 4 / 2;
else
  p += 3 % 1;
```

since x<5, i should go for the else condition, right?
My last question is that, after using `p += 3%1`, my p still remains 1, so do i return back to this loop (since p<12) or do I get out of this loop and proceed to line19? I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: x will increment after the attribution of sum.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. But I still don't get why sum=4 and not 5. Can you explain a little further?

Comment: x++ (the incrementation) is done after the current instruction, so x is 2 when the sum is calculated. After that, it will become 3.

Comment: If you use pre incrementation (++x), like Alexey said, the incrementation will be done before calculating the sum, so the result will be 5.

Comment: oh thanks! I keep getting confused with the pre/post incrementaton. Now i get what's happening. One more thing,can you tell me what happens after i calculate sum? Afterwards, p still remains as 1, does that mean i keep going back inside this while loop? If p doesn't equal 12, i won't be able to leave this loop. I'm not sure if I'm thinking this through right.

Comment: After 3 iterations, I think, x will become bigger than 5, so p will increase by 2 each time from now on (x>5 -> p=p+2). Eventually p will become 12, or bigger and will leave the while loop.

Comment: okay. i finally get what's going on. Since i basically kept getting my pre/post increments wrong, i got all sorts of bad output. woahh, i'm really happy coz i've been stuck with this tracing problem for a while now.

Comment: You're welcome! You should, though, follow VinhNT advide and learn how to use a debugger. It's not that hard and is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

In line 12 you are using [post increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java) (`x++`). You should use pre increment `++x`.

Post increment puts the current value of `x` in your statement, then increases `x`.

Pre increment initially increases `x` and after that puts result into your statement.

Answer (score 0):

At your first time, `3%1=0`
`p +=3%1` => `p+=0` thats why p still remains 1

Comment: The thing is I did figure out that p=1 but basically I have confusions regarding line 12, which is asks me for the sum. I get 5 but it's actually 4. Do you know what's happening up there?

Comment: And after i get p=1, do I go back to this while loop? how do I get out of this while loop? It looks as if p will keep remaining as 1.

Comment: After 4 first loops, x will be 6, then, p will be re-assign in statement p+=4/2 which gives p+=2; then p will be 3,5,7,9,11,13 for each time the loop pass. When p=13, the loop is terminate

Comment: @Hades, I think you should learn how to debug in a IDE tool like eclipse/netbean to run step by step and see how it works

Comment: Alright, thanks, I understand what's happening now.Yeah. i kinda avoided going for debugging even though I keep seeing it's important that I learn by now how to debug.

Comment: It is not quite hard, see this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: Okay, I'll definitely check out the tutorial!