# why is incrementing i value with pre and post operator giving a strange result?

Tags: java

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 5){
    i = i++;
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

The output is 000000... infinite

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 5)
{
    i = ++i;
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

The output is 12345

Comment: `i` is assigned the existing value of `i` before `i++`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java

Comment: after assigned old value to i, i is incrementing as post increment operator use then why next line i value not changed?

Comment: The order of assignment and post increment is not what you assume. The assignment of the old value occurs after the post increment operator.

Comment: I think this is NOT a duplicate, but it is a valid question to ask as to why the variable i never incremented, and I find the answers provided so far missed the mark.

Comment: @ndlu i is incremented (through the post increment operator) but **after that** the assignment of the old value (before the post increment) overwrites the incrmeneted value. What is unclear about that ordering?

Comment: @ndlu: the snippet `i=i++;` is executed is `{int tmpi=i; i++; i=tmpi;}` and this is required through the language specification. You seem to assume that it is executed and `i=i; i++;` and this assumption is wrong.

Comment: In post increment value incrementing after assign a  old value

Comment: @Thomas Kläger - your breakdown example is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. viren shah hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or
>   after (postfix) the operand. The code result++; and ++result; will
>   both end in result being incremented by one. The only difference is
>   that the prefix version (++result) evaluates to the incremented value,
>   whereas the postfix version (result++) evaluates to the original
>   value. If you are just performing a simple increment/decrement, it
>   doesn't really matter which version you choose. But if you use this
>   operator in part of a larger expression, the one that you choose may
>   make a significant difference.

From [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

`++i` returns `i+1` but `i++` returns `i`.

Comment: but after the execution of i++ mean next line i value should be change.

Comment: yeah, `i++` makes `i` changed. But after that, by `i = i++`, `i` is assigned `i++`'s return value, `i`.