# Recursive Outputs

Tags: java, recursion, output

This is the following code I had for a recursion question

Is anyone able to run me through how the output is 24?

To prove how confused I am, I thought the output would have been 6, 12, 20 ,1

```
package Examples;

public class QuestionDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(recCall(2));
}

public static int recCall(int num) {

    if (num == 5) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return num * recCall(++num);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Walk through why you thought the output would be that. And do you mean you thought it would have 4 outputs?

Comment: your not looping your println so 4 output is not possible

Comment: Note that the return of each recurse is being multiplied by the passed number.

Comment: @simigami 50 rep is easy to get. Ask a few good questions, and you'll get it. Posting non-answers as answers hurts the asker because it makes it less likely someone will post a real answer.

Comment: I was going along the lines so num == 2 , therefore 2 * recCall(3) and carried on looping printing out, now i realise how wrong I was, I think it has clicked that it will be 2 x 3 x 4 x 1? which then equals 24

Comment: Who went around downvoting half the answers? Please comment. That's rather rude.

Answer (score 2):

You have 4 recursive calls
first one when you call recCall(2)
then recCall(3), recCall(4) and recCall(5) 
recCall(5) returns 1
recCall(4) returns 4*1
recCall(3) returns 3*4*1
recCall(2) returns 2*3*4*1 = 24

Answer (score 2):

recCall(int num):

```
recall(2)
    |       | 
   2 *    recall(3)
              |       |
              3 *  recall(4)
                      |         |
                      4 *    recall(5)
                                |
                                1           



recall(2) = 24
            |       |
            2 *   12 = 24
                    |      |
                    3 *    4 = 12
                           |       |
                           4 *     1 = 4
                                   |
                                   1
```

Answer (score 1):

This recursion takes a **bottom-up** approach. First going deepest to find the value of the base case, before you can get the value of other recursive calls.

This is why you're getting **output** = 24:

```
                                       _
                                      /|\ 
                                     / | \
recCall(4) = 4 * recCall(5) = 4  +  /  |  \ // recCall(5) is your base case.
recCall(3) = 3 * recCall(4) = 12 +     |
-----------------------------------    |
recCall(2) = 2 * recCall(3) = 24       | // This was your first call to the recursive function.
```

You're not traversing through values, but rather **adding** them all up.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are using the `recCall(++num)`, and you are using `pre-increment` operator which increases value before calling the method.

Please read how ++ pre increment works in java :- [How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

So your recursive calls will look like below

```
 f(2)= 2*f(3)=2*12 = 24.
        f(3)=3*f(4)= 3*4=12
            f(4)=4*f(5) = 4*1
                f(5)= 1
```

hence it returns 24.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you try to move recall(++num) and put the new number which is `++num` so result will be `= 2 * 3 * 4` and in 5 it will return 1, so `2 * 3 * 4* 1`.