# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException during stack implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I am trying to implement stack but getting this error. I can not understand why I am getting this because I defined the size of an array.
my Error  : **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

```
ReverseStack(int n){
        top = - 1;
        size = n;
        a = new char[size];

    }
    boolean push(char c){
        if(top >=size ){
            System.out.println("Stack overflow");
            return false;
        }else{
            a[top++] = c;
            return true;
        }
    }
    char pop(){
        if(top<0){
            System.out.println("Stack underflow");
            return 0;
        }else{
            char c = a[top--];
            return c;
        }
    }
```

Method from where I am calling push operation.

```
public static void reverse(StringBuffer str){
        int n = str.length();
        ReverseStack obj = new ReverseStack(n);
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            obj.push(str.charAt(i));
        }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            char ch = obj.pop();
            str.setCharAt(i, ch);
        }
    }
```

Can some one please help me in that. Any code changes or new techniqe must be appriciated.

Comment: Please post what your error says to better help answer your question

Comment: @GrayCygnus Update my question

Comment: @shankysingh - he meant full stack trace.

Comment: Yes, as @BhavikPatel mentioned, your full stack trace to better debug your problem

Comment: @NathanHughes thanks I got the issue now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you starting your attribute `top` as `-1`

either

1- `top = 0;` on constructor

or

2- in `push` and `pop` method use `++top` and `--top`

see [How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java) for more info about the difference

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you more eloberate the ++top and top ++ difference.

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Comment: @shankysingh updated my answer

Comment: Thanks very helpfull.