# x = (x = 1) + (x = 2) * (++x) * (x++) - Why is the output of this expression 19?

Tags: java, operators

I executed the code and output was 19, but I don't understand why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int x = 0;
    x = (x = 1) + (x = 2) * (++x) * (x++);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: and why you think it should't be 19?

Comment: And what do you think it should be? And why?

Comment: run the program @EJP

Comment: running the program won't really answer his questions though ;) Only you can do that.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. You already told us what the result actually is. I don't need to run the program to know that. I asked what you think it should be, and you haven't answered that. I also asked you why, and you haven't answered that either.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java

Answer (score 8):

You evaluate the operands from left to right, and then evaluate the multiplication operators before the addition operator:

```
x = (x = 1) + (x = 2) * (++x)  *      (x++);

       1    +    (2    *   3   *       3     )  = 19

    assignment          pre            post
    operator            increment      increment
    returns the         returns the    returns the
    assigned value      incremented    value before
                        value          it was incremented
```

Comment: then it should increment another time for x++

Comment: @mahdi x++ increments x to 4, but returns 3.

Comment: @mahdi https://stackoverflow.com/a/2371162

Comment: The last `++` happens before the assignment of 19 to `x`, so the 4 is overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

its evaluated like this -

```
1+2*3*3
```

(x=1) - first x is set t 1
(x=2) - then x is set to 2
(++x) - then x is incremented to 3; pre-increment and affects the equation in this case
(x++) - the last was post increment; no effect on the equations

Answer (score 2):

as per my knowledge:

1 + 2*3*3 = 19