# Sort an Array - recursive call

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am writing code to sort an array in order. I checked some algorithm for sort and merge, however I found that if I just go through the array and compare every 2 elements and swap them and repeat that until the array is sorted. 
So if array[I] > array[i++], swap, repeat.

It is not working so far. I also need a break point to avoid stack overflow:  I need some help please

> Array:

```
    int[] newArray = new int[] {3,9,5,7,4,6,1};

    SortArray s = new SortArray();

    s.sortThisArray(newArray, 0, 0);
```

> Recursive function:

```
public String sortThisArray(int[] array, double counter, double a)
{
    int swap0 = 0; 
    int swap1 = 0; 

    if (a > 1000)
    {
        return "reached the end" ; 
    }

    for (int i =0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i++])
        {
            swap0 = array[i];
            swap1 = array[i++];
            array[i++] = swap0; 
            array[i] = swap1; 

            counter = counter++; 
            a = array.length * counter; 

            sortThisArray (array, counter, a); 
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j<array.length ; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[j]);
    }
    return "completed"; 
}
```

}

Comment: i++ increments i. You used it several times when you probably wanted to use i+1. counter = counter++; doesn't do anything. It increments counter and then assigns it back to the old value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java

Comment: Why not use standard sorting functions?

Comment: I am trying to resolve the time complexity, using the standard sorting functions is time efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are searching for is **recursive bubble sort** algorithm.

The main error is confusing i++ (which increments i every time) with i+1, that is only the position in the array after i, without incrementing. Then, there is no need to use double for counter, and also the a variable is not needed. You need only the length of the current segment, this way:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RecursiveBubbleSort {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] newArray = new int[] {3,9,5,7,4,6,1};

sortThisArray(newArray, newArray.length);

    System.out.println("Sorted array : ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
}

public static int[] sortThisArray(int[] array, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return array; //finished sorting
    }

    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if (array[i+1] < array[i]) {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return sortThisArray(array, n-1);
}

}
```

Comment: And hope the compiler is smart enough to remove tail recursion. Otherwise an array of even moderate size is going to blow the stack.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, I made changes to the code, and it now works. Sorting algorithms are not easy to grasp, will need to spend some more time to understand it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The ++ operator evalutes separately. So in the case i++, we will read i and then increment it by 1. And the other way around, ++i, would first apply the increment to i, and then read i. So when you want to check for the next element in the array, `[i+1]` is what you are looking for. With the same reasoning, can you figure out whats wrong with this line?

```
counter = counter++;
```

And do we even need it?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!