# Pre and post increment in java

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment

I know how pre and post increment operators work, but recently I found out a strange behavior in Java. What i knew so far was (as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java) as well):

```
a = 5;
i=++a + ++a + a++; =>
i=6 + 7 + 7; (a=8)
```

which clearly shows that the ++a returns the value after increment, a++ returns the value before increment. But very recently, I came across this piece of code:

```
int a = 0;
int b = a++;
int c = ++b;
System.out.println("b=" + b + "\nc=" + c);
```

The output to this piece of code is:

```
b=1
c=1
```

which is strange as a++ should return 0, and increment a, keeping the value of b to 0, as evident from the answer quoted above, while in the next line, b should be incremented first before the value is assigned to c, making it 1. What is happening here?

Comment: exactly what you said: "b should be incremented first" - so when you print b it is 1 then "value is assigned to c" which is 1

Comment: _What is happening here?_  An abomination.  Mixing increment (or decrement) operators with other operators is a recipe for confusion.

Comment: Everything happens on the third line.  At the start, b=0 as you say.  b then is pre-incremented to 1, and 1 is assigned to c.  That's it.

Comment: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/. `++` despite looking so cool has a measly rank of 15, while `=` sits there on the top!

Answer (score 4):

When int b = a++ is called, the value of a (0) is assigned to b (now 0), and then a is incremented to 1.

So, when int c = ++b is called, b is 0. b is then incremented to 1 (by ++b) and then its value is assigned to c.

At the end, b=1 and c=1

Answer (score 2):

What exactly you find as strange as it is the expected behavior...

> int a = 0; // declare a 
>   int b = a++; // declare b with the value of 0, a becomes 1 afterwards.
>   int c = ++b; // both c and b gets 0++ here -> 1

`System.out.println("b=" + b + "\nc=" + c);` prints the expected output.

```
b=1
c=1
```

Comment: oh yes. I am really sorry, I was completely ignoring the fact that ++b will change the value of b as well. closing the question. my bad

Comment: I think you could delete it as it has no value for the community.