# Assigning itself values in post increment and in pre increment

Tags: java

I'm new to the coding can anyone explain to me why below code is giving output as '6'

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 5;
        i = i++;
        i = ++i;
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the culprit --> `i = i++;`

Comment: The middle statement is effectively a no-op. `i = i++;` does not change `i`.

Answer (score 1):

`i = i++;` This line assign `5` to `i` again you can run this code to ensure about that:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 5;
        i = i++;
        System.out.println(i);
        i = ++i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

For more information visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

Comment: why this line "i = i++; This line assign 5 to i " ? can you explain?

Comment: @user3359125 this is what post increment do for us. It first assign current value of `i` to itself then increment it by one