# Way to set next array item as new value of a variable?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have an array of the alphabet and say if the user has the letter A, then using this method the users' letter will change from A to B.

```
public class Letter {
    private char letter;

    public Letter(){
        letter = 'A';
    }

public char volgende(){
        char[] alfabet = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
        for (int i=0; i <= alfabet.length-1 ; i++) {
            if (alfabet[i] == letter){
                letter = alfabet[i++];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Nieuwe letter is " + letter);
        return letter;
    }
```

I expected this code to turn the default letter A to B, but it doesn't. I've tried replacing the alfabet[i++] with a char 'B', but that works, so i dont know why alfabet[i++] wouldn't, since it's the next item in the array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You are using the post increment operator. You need to use the pre increment operator e.g.

`letter = alfabet[++i]`

By the way it is spelled alphabet and keep in mind that `Z` will result in an IndexOutOfBoundsException error since it is the last index.

Comment: And i added and else if that when the letter is Z, it goes back to alfabet[0]