# Tricky basic java operations

Tags: java, math, operation

I got these 2 different codes in Java that I can't understand how they produce these specific outputs.

They seemed to work in 2 different logic and I can't figure it out!

```java
int a = 5;
int b = 4;
a -= (b++) + ++a; // For more confusing results replace -= with += and see how the logic changes.
System.out.println(a); // Output: -5
```

and

```java
int c = 8;
c += ++c;
System.out.println(++c); // Output: 18
```

How does each situation work and how are they producing these specific outputs?

Comment: You should check the difference between post and preincrement

Comment: Not a dupe, as depends on how `a -= x` and `++a` interact. The key point seems to be the rewriting `a -= x`  as `a = a -x` happens before a pre increment operator.

Comment: I was unsure to ask this simple question but really struggled with it, and I didn't know what to search on google because I already know how increment, decrement, pre and post work so I decided to ask here which was my last solution. Before I asked here and while I was still playing around with these operations that I posted, in my mind and for some reason, I was sure that I tried b++ and (b++) and realized that (b++) acts like ++b, however, I was certainly wrong. But thanks for the quick response from everyone especially Nexevis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major difference here is what `post` and `pre` increment are.  These determine whether the value is increased *before* evaluation, or afterward.

Here is how the first case breaks down mathematically:

`a = 5 - (4 + 6)`, which reduces to `-5`.

Note that `a` is increased from `++a` AKA `preincrement`  *before* the math is done, however `b` is calculated as `4`.  Another thing to note is the `a` used from the `-=` uses the *original* `a` value, regardless of post or pre increment.

The second equation reduces to this mathematically:

`c = 8 + 9` which reduces to `17`.

The output prints `18` because your `System.out.print(++c)` increments it one more time before output due it being preincrement.  Note if the `print` statement used `c++`, the value would print to `17`.

The chart for operator precedence can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).  Note that assignment has lower precedence than the unary/postfix operators.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the [Operator Precedence](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html) in Java. Check that table and figure out which operation takes place first and which last.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 4;
a -= (b++) + ++a; // => 5 -= (4) + 6
int c = 8;
c += ++c; // => 9 += 9
```

The main diff is thet:

++a and ++c increments the value and immediately returns it.

b++ returns the value and then increments it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in the order of ++.  While both increase the variable, ++a will pass the original value to the operation chain your in middle of; while a++ would pass the new value.  So for your first example:

```
++a --> a is now 6; but the equation is using 5:
a -= (b++) + 5;
b++ --> b is now 5;
a -= 5 + 5;
a -= 10;
? = 5 - 10;


a = a - 5 + 5;
a = 5 - 5 + 5;
a = -10;
```

(You should have enough to trace the second example).

For a list of operations try [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm).  Some more increment examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example is `

```
int x=3,y=3;
x += ++x;
y+= y++;
```

at the x x is 7 and y is 6. Precedence alone is not enough to explain the behaviour. Using precedence the second line would be `x += (++x)`, i.e. increment x and return its value, (x is now 4); next we have `x+=4` which would return 8.

Instead, it seems better to treat `x += w` as a short hand for `x = x + w`, this rewriting happens before evaluation. In our case the rewriting is `x = x + ++x` interpreted as `x = (x + (++x))`. So interpreted as

```
x = ( 3 + (++x))
x = ( 3 +  4 )       x is 4
x = 7                x is 7
```

A simlar system works to the y equation giving y = 6 at the end.