# How to do pre increment without using ++I?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, pre-increment

I don't think that the following:

```
i += 1
```

or

```
i = i + 1
```

is the same as ++i. Or am I wrong? Is there any way to do pre increment without using ++ operator?

Comment: I believe there's lots out there on this. Your two statements are equivalent to ++i or i++ if they standalone (except maybe for some performance considerations). Where things get interesting is if you were to say things like array[i++] or array[++i]

Comment: Is there any way to use preincrement without the ++ operator? Yes, `i = i + 1` then use `i`. :)

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. Unless for very simple expressions (like a loop condition), it is better to avoid the `++` or `--` operators.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments so posting related stackoverflow question here:

[How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy already commented, i+=1; and i=i+1; are equivalent to ++i or i++ if they standalone lines of code.
To achieve pre/post increment you will have to do the increment before/after the line where you want to use the variable as per the case.

eg- for post increment of a variable named i:

```
//use value of i here
i += 1;
```

for pre increment:

```
i += 1;
//use value of i here
```

In case of a loop, post increment is pretty straight forward:

```
for(var i=someValue; i<maxValue; i+=1){
//code here
}
```

For pre increment:

```
var i = someValue + 1;
for(; i<maxValue; i+=1){
//code here
}
```