# Java Postincrement and Operator Precedence

Tags: java, operator-keyword, operator-precedence, post-increment

I'm a bit confused about this code:

```
int r = 7;
boolean result1 = r == r++; //
boolean result2 = r++ == r; //

System.out.println(result1);
System.out.println(result2);
```

I would think both are true, but result1 is true and result2 is false.

The Oracle tutorial doesn't really help, in the Java Language Specification I also don't find any answer. So far, I don't understand, how the post-increment operator has the highest operator precedence.

Comment: Try saying out loud, for `result1` "Is 7 equal to 7, then incremented 7 by one?" and, for `result2` "is 8 incremented by 1 equal to 8?"

And you can also experiment with parentheses around things to force precedence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

Comment: Even in Java, it's possible to write very obscure code, and this is an example. More than operator precedence, hopefully this teaches a lesson about coding style - that we'll never ever write lines like these in production code.

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with operator precedence, but with order of evaluation, which is left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Java evaluate expressions one by one.

When it evaluate `r++` result is `7`, but side effect applied immediately, so when it evaluates `r`, result is new value of `r` (`8`).

This is the reason why increment/decrement expression should not be used in complex expressions.