# Operator Oddities in Java

Tags: java

```
int number = 10;
int result = 0
        for (int i = 10; i <= 50; i += 10) {
            number = i;
            result = --number - number--;
            System.out.println("i = " + i + ", number = " + number +
                    ", result = " + result);
```

The result is

i = 10, number = 8, result = 0

i = 20, number = 18, result = 0

i = 30, number = 28, result = 0

i = 40, number = 38, result = 0

i = 50, number = 48, result = 0

I want to know how the operators work step by step in  `result = --number - number-- ;` .
What are the values of number while executing the above statement?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? They're pretty good at this kind of stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

Comment: Java evaluates left-to-right, irrespective of operator precedence. So, it evaluates `--number`, then `number--`, then subtracts the results.

Comment: Why substracting 9-10 results 0.

Comment: because its not subtracting 9-10. It is subtracting 9-9. Why do you think `number` is still 10 at that moment when it will already have evaluated `--number` at that point which will have decremented number from its original value?

Comment: yes i got it.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only this much code is enough to make you understand this concept:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 10;
        int result = --number - number--;
        System.out.println("number = " + number + ", result = " + result);
    }
}
```

This is how it is processed:

```
--number => number = number - 1 => number = 10 - 1 => number = 9 
result = --number - number-- => result = 9 - 9 => result = 0
number-- => number = number - 1 => number = 9 - 1  => number = 8
```

Thus the output:

```
number = 8, result = 0
```

Comment: result = number-- - number++ * --number;

Comment: Can you explain me internal working of above codes? Thank you, sir.

Comment: @EmilyWatson - Same as I've explained above, it will be evaluated as `result = 10 - 9 * 9 =  - 71`

Answer (score 2):

To understand what `--number` and `number--` mean, it is useful to consider that these are both *expressions* with *side-effects*

- An `expression` is a part of the code which has a value.
- A `side-effect` means that something changes as a result of evaluating that expression.

Looking at each of them in turn:

- `--number`'s side effect is to decrease the `number`'s value by 1; its value is the number stored in `number` after decreasing it.
- `number--`'s side effect is to increase the `number`'s value by 1; its value is the number stored in `number` *before* decreasing it.

Because Java evaluates expressions left-to-right, in `--number - number--`, `--number` is evaluated first; then `number--` is evaluated next.

- The initial value of `number` is some value, say, `X`
- The value of `--number` is `X - 1`; the value stored in `number` afterwards is `X - 1`.
- The value of `number--` is the same value, `X - 1`; the value stored in `number` afterwards is `X - 2`.
- Hence, `--number - number--` is `(X - 1) - (X - 1)`, which is zero
- The final value of `number` is `X - 2`.

Comment: This answer helps me to understand.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different explanation.  Your code.  `Let i = 10`

```
number = i;
result = --number - number--;
```

Is the same as

```
number = i;
number = number - 1;  // number is now 9
result = number;      // result is now 9
result = number - number;  // result is now 0
number = number - 1;       // number is now 8
```

so the first line would be

```
i = 10, number = 8, result = 0
```

Pre-increments and decrements are applied **before** using the value, and post increments and decrements are applied **after** using the value.

Comment: This help me alot. Thanks so much.