# How are y=x++ and y=x-- different when the assignment operators has the least priority?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I'm new to java.
Just found out that in the expression,
`y=x++`, y assumes the value of x and x becomes +1.
Forgive me if I sound stupid, but according to the [order of precedence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys0KN.png), assignment operators is at the end. So isn't x++ supposed to happen first followed by the assignment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a feeling you are confused between y = x++; and y = ++x;

Comment: Yes, but `++` and `--` are kind of special, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java). That's why I suggest to use `++` and `--` only as standalone expression.

Comment: correct about precedence but [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2-200): "... The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored. ,,," (The value being assigned is not the variable's one (that would kind of mean higher precedence of assignment) but the result of the post-increment **expression**, by definition, the variable value **before** incrementing)

Comment: It's not about priority. The postincrement/postdecrement operators update the operand after its value has been taken, that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q: So isn't `x++` supposed to happen first followed by the assignment.

A: Yes.  And that is what happens.  The statement `y = x++;` is equivalent to the following:

```
temp = x;      // | This is 'x++'
x = x + 1;     // | (note that 'temp' contains the value of 'x++')

y = temp;      // This is the assignment.
```

But as you see, the order of the operations (`++` and `=`)  doesn't affect what the operations actually do.

And therefore ...

> Q: How are `y=x++` and `y=x--` different when the assignment operators has the least priority?

A: They aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence and evaluation order are two different concepts and they're not related.

If you have `a() + b() * c()`, that doesn't mean that `b()` and `c()` get invoked first because `*` has a higher precedence than `+`. `a()` still gets evaluated first. Evaluation order is typically left-to-right unless stated otherwise.

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of
> operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order,
> namely, from left to right.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7

Answer (score 0):

`y=x++` is assigning the value of x to y and then x gets incremented. The `x++` operation is called a post-increment.

Here's some code that you can run for illustration:

```
int x = 0;
System.out.println("Illustration of post-increment");
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(x++);
System.out.println(x);

int y = 0;
System.out.println("Illustration of pre-increment");
System.out.println(y);
System.out.println(++y);
System.out.println(y);
```