# Why is pre and post increment operator not working in recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, post-increment, pre-increment

I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Screen.clear();
        System.out.println(depth(5,0));
        
    }

public static int depth(int n, int depth){
        System.out.println(depth);
        if(n == 0)return depth;
        else{
           System.out.println(depth);          
           return depth(n-1, depth++);
        }
        
    }
```

why does this always print out 0, n times?  Why isn't depth being incremented?

Comment: 1. you don't have any pre-increment here. 2. post-increment will *first* return the value *then* increment. And since you only pass in the returned value, it's only the one before it is incremented. So, zero. Same as if you do `int depth = 0; System.out.println(depth++)` you'd still get a zero printed. That's how post-increment always works. Recursion has no real bearing on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you aren't pre-incrementing. Your function is passing 0 before it increments, thereby effectively not incrementing. try this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        Screen.clear();
        System.out.println(depth(5,0));
        
    }

public static int depth(int n, int depth){
        System.out.println(depth);
        if(n == 0)return depth;
        else{
           System.out.println(depth);          
           return depth(n-1, ++depth);
        }
    }
```

or (if you want to use the post-increment)

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        Screen.clear();
        System.out.println(depth(5,0));
        
    }

public static int depth(int n, int depth){
        System.out.println(depth);
        if(n == 0)return depth;
        else{
           System.out.println(depth++);          
           return depth(n-1, depth);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Almost always a bad idea to increment in a print statement.

Comment: Just because something "works" doesn't mean it should be used...

Comment: indeed. my recommended answer is the former code snippet.

Comment: @DCR What do you mean? [pre-increment definitely works](https://ideone.com/ehLf6U). There is no reason for it to not work.

Comment: @DCR both versions work. Check out VLAZ sandbox environment that he linked  [above](https://ideone.com/ehLf6U)

Comment: you are correct, they do work!

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call `depth`, you pass 5 for `n` and 0 for `depth` (btw, in general it's a bad idea to have the same name for methods and parameters). You are doing it like this:

```
System.out.println(depth(5,0));
```

Later on, you are calling it like this:

```
return depth(n-1, depth++);
```

Let's see what happens:

- you subtract 1 from `n` and pass the result to the new function call
- you pass the unchanged `depth` and then increment it (`depth++` evaluates to its initial value and increments it without, whereas `++depth` would increment it first and evaluate the result)

So, these are the values of `n` and `depth` respectively upon each call:

- 5, 0
- 4, 0
- 3, 0
- 2, 0
- 1, 0
- 0, 0

To understand this even better, let's try the following:

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println(i++); //1
System.out.println(i); //2
int j = 1;
System.out.println(++j); //2
System.out.println(j); //2
```