Precedence of pre-increment operation over post-increment operation
package test;
 
public class Test {
     
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 12;
        
        System.out.println( ++a == 11 || b++ == 12);
        System.out.println("a= "+a);
        System.out.println("b= "+b);
    }
}

output:
true
a= 11
b= 12

As per the Java precedence, post-increment operator has higher precedence than pre-increment operator.
Then, why isn't the post increment operation evaluated first instead of pre-increment operation?
I understand that short circuiting has been performed here.
++a == 11 is evaluated first, and since it is true, b++ == 12 has not been evaluated.
Does this imply that logical operators have higher precedence when compared with all other operators in Java?
I tried evaluating the expression ++a == 11 || b++ == 12 in a Java program and expected that the post-increment operation b++ would be evaluated first because the post-increment operator has higher precedence than the pre-increment operator. I expected the output to show true, a= 11, and b= 13 if b++ was executed.
What actually resulted?
The output was:
true
a= 11
b= 13


This isn't a question about precedence at all.

Precedence is about argument grouping, not evaluation order. Higher-precedence operators do not have to execute first.

This question is similar to: What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java  . You can explore further by browsing these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+operator+precedence

All binary operators (such as your logical OR), with the exception of the assignment operators, are evaluated from left to right. Your assumption about short circuiting is correct. Your assumption about the precedence of logical operators is not so correct, in fact precedence plays no part in any of this. For reference, only the ternary operator and the assignment operators have lower precedence than the logical OR, as you can see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2F/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html
Also consider that the prefix and postfix increments work in different ways, which can affect how your code behaves. In any case, in your code, a gets incremented first, then it is compared with 11. As that is true, the second operand of the logical OR does not get evaluated. Compare it with the following:
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 12;
    
    System.out.println( ++a == 11 | b++ == 12);
    System.out.println("a= "+a);
    System.out.println("b= "+b);
}

Output:
true
a= 11
b= 13

"in fact precedence plays no part in any of this."
I would love to get more insight on this because as per the below statement

If you have any further questions you can create a new question with all the necessary details. Your comment as it is written is unclear to me

Apologies for the incomplete comment.
"in fact precedence plays no part in any of this."
I would love to get more insight on this because as per the below statement
System.out.println( ++a == 11 || b++ == 12);
These are the operators that are currently present:
++a : unary pre increment operator
== : equality operator
|| : Logical OR operator

If we look at the Java operator precedence table, the unary pre-increment operator must be performed before the Logical OR operator and equality operator.
Hence, in the statement --->
System.out.println( ++a == 11 || b++ == 12);
++a and b++ should have been evaluated first.
Rather, we evaluate the expression ++a == 11 first and if it comes out true, we short-circuit it.
Please help me fill my missing knowledge. Ty

Again, precedence is irrelevant here. I don't know what you're not understanding, the only thing that matters in your code is not precedence but shortcircuiting, in my answer you have an example that doesn't shortcircuit and therefore evaluates both increments. If you have a new question, please create a new question, don't use the comments of an answer to ask new questions.
